# How to sort elements alphabetically in a list that have same numeric values

Tags: bash

**First of all, I mustn't use awk or sed!**

I counted the number of times a command was used in bash history. I've used the following code:

```
cat ${!#} | cut -f 1 -d " " | sort | uniq -c | sort -n | sort -r
```

Note that cat ${!#} is history.txt by deafult and I used cut to get rid of the numbered lines. Also I had to use `sort -r` at the end, otherwise I'd get the output ascending rather then descending (why is that?).

Ok my main question is sorting the commands with the same number of repetitions. Currently I'm getting this output:

```
seq 3
ps 2
echo 2
cut 2
uname 1
nl 1
cmp 1
```

But I need to get the following output:

```
seq 3
cut 2
echo 2
ps 2
cmp 1
diff 1
nl 1
uname 1
```

So yeah. Sort the commands by number of repetitions and if any of them are the same, sort them alphabetically.

I tried to tackle this with another sort, but haven't had much success thus far.

Also is it just a coincidence that commands in my output are reversed from the desired output? Or are they sorted descending by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with GNU sort:

```
sort -k2nr -k1,1 file
```

Output:

```
seq 3
cut 2
echo 2
ps 2
cmp 1
nl 1
uname 1
```

Comment: sort -k2nr -k1,1r
I had to reverse the first column too, which is weird, but it works. Thanks!